# transformPointCloud unconnected to tf_broadcaster

Tags: ros, pcl, tf-listener, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the code tf_broadcaster from the ROS tutorial, but I am using "base_link" and "velodyne"  as parent and children in the transformation.
I am using "velodyne" because is the frame_id of the pointcloud that my scanner is publishing, please let me know if it is not necessary to have the same name.

And I am using this code for subscribing a pointcloud2 and tf messages and publish a new pointcloud2:

```
ros::Publisher pub;
tf::Transform transform;
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg2;

void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& msg) 
{ 
  tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("velodyne", *msg, msg2, tf_listener);    
  pub.publish(msg2);        
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "pc2tfpc");
  ros::NodeHandle n ; 
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("velodyne_points", 1, chatterCallback); 
  pub=n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("tfpc",1); 
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I can compile code and execute but the new pointcloud2 has not been transformed with the published tf (I checked it on rviz)

rostopic echo /tf shows the right transformation.

rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph shows that my code is not subscribed to /tf

If I change the target_frame to "velodyne" (  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("velodyne", *msg, msg2, tf_listener); )
then I get this error in the execution:
"base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

Anybody has an idea about what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236175/transformpointcloud-unconnected-to-tf_broadcaster/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your tf tree is set up correctly, `velodyne_pointcloud` provides a [transform nodelet](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud#TransformNodelet) that can perform this operation for you.

In your case, set the `frame_id` parameter to "base_link". (The default is "odom", which is usually what people want.)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2016-06-08**:
I run the velodyne_node to publish raw data, the tf_broadcaster from the tutorial (parent "base_link", children "velodyne") and the transform_node _frame_id:=/base_link and a calibration file. I get error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past...from frame [velodyne] to [base_link]

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-08**:
Sounds like something is wrong with your ```tf`` tree or your clock.